# Software to cd (change directories) into .jar/.ear files?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, jar, compression

Is there any software/script that will allow me to cd (change directories) into .jar/.ear/.zip files and edit the contents of the files it contains?  I'm working on a large EJB project (yuck), and I frequently find myself in situations like the following:

```
something.ear/
|-- something.jar/
|   `-- fileINeedToEdit.xml
```

I work primarily via the command line (Mac/Linux), so I find myself decompressing the files with `jar -xvf`, editing the file I need to edit, and then recompressing with `jar -cvf`.  Obviously, this becomes a major headache after the first few times.

I'd like to be able to treat the compressed files as directories, and simply `cd` (or some alternate command) to the file I want to edit.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: you should have an efficient build system that would let you edit the source file and rebuild the .ear/.jar very quickly instead of the way you are doing it. Ant is very good for this.

Comment: Listen to fuzzy. You're doing it wrong.

Comment: You are right, but this is not an option for various (corporate) reasons that I cannot change.  We are a small team working alongside a larger team, so we aren't allowed to modify the build at this point.  In addition, the build process and the version control (PVCS - yuck) are slow and unwieldy.

Comment: If the corporation is the thing causing the problem, I suggest you replace it with some other corporation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments to your question, an automated build should allow you to make this kind of changes easily and is the right way to go. But if you insist in this direction, check [fuse-zip](http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/), it provides the ability for zip files to be mounted on any directory mount point.

Comment: I had mild success using fuze-zip and overriding the `cd` command to mount with fuze-zip if the arguments were the proper type (zip|jar).  However, the fact that changes to the mounted zip are not persisted until it is unmounted sort of threw a wrench in my plans.

Comment: @Segphault: Can't say if this is the "normal" behavior. But I understand it's consequently not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general strategies. Either use software that can mount the jars as pseudo file systems. That allows you to work exactly like you are used to, but I'm uncertain how well Mac OS supports user-space filesystems. Or use a tool that already has in-place editing support, like the Windows explorer or a more powerful editor (e.g. emacs).

Answer (score 1):

I use one of this application If I want to check something in jar or ear file

- Krusader (file manager from KDE) - it allows to investigate jar, ear or war file, but unfortunatelly doesn't work well with nested jars files
- mc (Midnight Commander) - it works pretty well with ear, jar or war, event with nested jars